# Sort SortedDictionary by to the value

Tags: c#, linq, sorteddictionary

I have sorted dictionary like below:

```
var map = new SortedDictionary<string, List<Account>>();
```

I need to sort it by value size (so List>.Count).
How do I do that?

I tried as suggested by this forum:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Account>>> myList = map.ToList();
            myList.Sort(delegate (KeyValuePair<string, List<Account>> pair1,
                                    KeyValuePair<string, List<Account>> pair2)
            {
                return pair1.Value.Count.CompareTo(pair2.Value.Count);
            }
            );
```

but that didn't work

Comment: `SortedDictionary` sorts by key, so you can't do what you want with it.

Comment: A `SortedDictionary` sorts its items by key. You're asking to sort by list size, which is the value. What's the point using a `SortedDictionary` instead of a simpler `Dictionary`?

Comment: You can't sort any type of dictionary itself that way. What you can do is use LINQ to generate an enumerable list from the dictionary by calling `OrderBy`, e.g. `myDictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.Count)`. Like any LINQ results, you can loop over that list. This is not ideal if you need to access items in that order a lot because the sorting will be done every time you access the data. You could create an array or generic list from the results but that may not be valid if you change one of the values. The alternative would be a custom collection class.

Comment: *"that didn't work"*. That's never an adequate description. What actually did happen? You do realise that that code is creating a new list and sorting that, not sorting the original dictionary, right?

Answer (score 2):

While shown method should work (and it did for me), I would suggest to use the LINQ here:

```cs
List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Account>>> myList = map
    .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.Count) // OrderByDescending if higher counts needed first
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to sort it by value size (so List>.Count). How do I do that?

What is "it"? Do you want as a result a Dictionary, or a sequence of `List', ordered by descending number of elements in the List? Next time consider to be more specific about your requirements.

If you want a sequence of `List<Account>`, the first List in the sequence being the largest, do the following:

```
SortedDictionary<string, List<Account>> map = ...
IEnumerable<List<Account>> accountListsInMap = map
    .Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value);
IEnumerable<List<Account>> listsOrderedByDescendingSize = accountListsInMap
    .OrderBy(accountList => accountList.Count);
```

Of course you can do this in one big LINQ statement. Nut sure though whether this will improve efficiency. However it will deteriorate readability.